# How to write below code in any other way?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How can I rewrite the following comprehesion?

```
positive_crawls = [{'url': page['url'], 'hour': hour-1, 'updated': True} 
                   for page in crawl_json 
                   for hour in page['positive checks']]
```

Comment: You mean to ask how to expand it into a loop structure?

Comment: @AmitPanthi, what is the goal of your rewrite? I mean you can use for loops, but probably what you already have is more efficient than using two for loops?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to rewrite that comprehension using loops instead, this is the way:

```
positive_crawls = []

for page in crawl_json:
    for hour in page['positive checks']:
        positive_crawls.append({'url': page['url'], 'hour': hour-1, 'updated': True})
```

However, keep in mind that it is very likely that your comprehension is faster than using this two for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, without a goal for the rewrite in mind there's lot's of room for interpretation.

Here's one

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Crawl:
    url: str
    hour: int
    updated: bool = True

def get_crawls(crawl_json):
    for page in crawl_json:
        for hour in page['positive checks']:
            yield Crawl(page['url'], hour - 1).asdict()

positive_crawls = list(get_crawls(crawl_json))
```